# template class multiple definition

Tags: c++, templates

I have a simple hash table template,

```
template <class K, class V, long H(K)>
class HashTableAbs{/* .... */}
//where K is key type, V is value type, H gives hash code for K value
```

and simple inheritor class

```
template <class K, class V, long H(K)>
class HashTable:public HashTableAbs<K, V, H> {};
```

and i want to specialize this template for string, with my default hash function

```
template <class V> 
class HashTable<std::string, V, strSimpleHash>:public HashTableAbs<std::string, V, strSimpleHash> {};
//where strSimpleHash is long strSimpleHash(std::string)
```

But when i trying to compile this compiler write this

```
test.o: In function `strSimpleHash(std::string)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `strSimpleHash(std::string)'
/tmp/main-i7yPhc.o:main.cc:(.text+0x0): first defined here
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

(test includes hashtable.h where HashTable is defined)
strSimpleHash is defined only in hashtable.h

Is there way out?
PS sorry for my writing mistakes. English in not my native language

Comment: did you define strSimpleHash before or after your template specialisation? It needs to be before.

Comment: i defined it before template and template specialisation

Comment: Please show more, code, notably the part where you define `strSimpleHash`, for more complete answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is not really related to templates. It is a multiple definition of a function. I guess you have defined `strSimpleHash` in a header without using `inline` (you didn't add the code where you define this function).

You asked in your comments a way to use `HashTable` like the following:

```
HashTable<std::string, int> // (ie, without passing the 3rd argument)
```

This is not directly possible. Althought you can specify a default value for a template argument (but not in a specialization), for example:

```
template<int n = 0> struct dummy {};
dummy<> obj;
```

in your case you cannot do that, because the general case of your template does not accept only functions of type `long(std::string)`.
However, it is possible to workaround this by assigning a default function for each possible type. Note that you should use pointer-to-function, as the code is a little clearer:

```
// A C++03-style template typedef
template<typename K>
struct HashFunc
{
    typedef long (*type)(K);
};

// The default value. Defined only for some cases,
// compile error for not handled cases
template<typename K>
struct DefaultHash;

template<>
struct DefaultHash<std::string>
{
    // Static constant pointer-to-function, pointing to the hash func.
    static constexpr HashFunc<std::string>::type func = &strSimpleHash;
};

// The HashTable class
template <class K, class V, typename HashFunc<K>::type H = DefaultHash<K>::func>
class HashTable
{
};

template <class V> 
class HashTable<std::string, V, strSimpleHash>
{
};
```

And then you can use it as you wanted, omitting the third template parameter. Note that this code [compiles on gcc](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2pJQWv%240), but [not on clang](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4sq88k%240). *(Actually, I'm not sure about which compiler is right...)*

Comment: Great! I added inline to strSimpleHash and it compiled. But when i trying to define HashTable<std::string, int>* table, compiler write: test.cpp:126:17: error: too few template arguments for class template 'HashTable'
void printTable(HashTable<std::string, int> *table)

Comment: Great! For what you have put in the comment, you forgot to pass the function: `HashTable<std::string,int,strSimpleHash>* table;`.

Comment: can i specialize my template, to make this (HashTable<std::string, int> *table) valid?

Comment: i am sorry, i have switched to gcc, and forgot it :(